# Оптимизация SQL запросов

Tags: sql, оптимизация, sql-server, запрос

Здравствуйте, у меня больше миллиона строк в БД (`MS SQL`), мне бы хотелось узнать как можно оптимизировать запросы в данном случае выборки из БД. И кто нибудь знает, есть ли толк в квадратных скобках при запросе, например:

```
SELECT [id_mark] FROM [dbo].[GET_SPR_BY_NAME] WHERE [mark]= 127
```

Или толку нет их писать!

Comment: Ускорить запрос можно только зная SQL и структуру таблиц, участвующих в запросе, иначе это гадание на кофейной гуще.

Наличие индексов ускоряет выборку, но замедляет вставку/обновление данных, поэтому использовать индексы следует аккуратно.

К тому же - существенно ускорить запрос можно не индексами, а изменив запрос. Но для этого надо знать конечную цель запроса и видеть сам запрос - может быть вместо LEFT JOIN подойдет простой INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Квадратные скобки - это исключительно особенность MS SQL, скорости они вашему запросу не добавят, и предназначены вовсе не для этого. Для чего они все же нужны, говорится вот [тут](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/db/3157045.all)

Comment: Всё спасибо прочитал!

Answer (score 3):

Квадратные скобки врядли сделают запросы быстрее (если сильно-сильно придираться, то чем длиннее запрос, тем дольше его передавать по сети, тем больше он потребует память, дольше парсить... да, это замедление будет доли процента, но на миллионы запросов может быть существенно. Но кто видел код:) поэтому даже не знаю, может у МС все как раз наоборот).

Но больше ускорение можно получить, если расставить правильно индексы. Особенно индексы хороши, если вставок мало, а выборок много. В вышеприведенном случае индекс нужен по полю `mark`.